# How to select html tag of particular index in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am using slick carousel slider.

By using the events method i am getting the index number of slides now how can i

enter the html tags of particular index?

Comment: You need to show your code to get a better answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the class you can use `:eq()` like this

`$(".some_class:eq(3)")`

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alenjoy333/03o3vp6h/1/)

Comment: id is unkown i want to enter the html tag of index number as in slider index number keeps on changing so i want to select the elements inside the index

Comment: <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 testimonialset">
              <div class="testimonial-block ">
             <div class="testimonial-image ">
             <p>PHOTO</p>
             </div>
             <div class="testimonial-detail">
             <p>We are happy with the support staffs for their prompt response and fast service. We recommend this service.</p>
             </div>   this is my html so i want to change the class of these on active through index

Comment: dude what is the class name of the slide

Comment: Wow thank you bro saved me a lot of time now i am currently having  problem removing class back (shy)

Comment: bro thank u so much brooooooo its been 2days i been stucked :)